# How to open multiple google-chrome on multiple remote debugging ports?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, debugging

I connect selenium to an existing chrome session by opening chrome with

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\selenum\ChromeProfile"

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222') # Recommended is 9222
chrome_driver =  "Data/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I am doing a project where I would have to open multiple windows of chrome on different ports for chrome. So I am looking to open another instance on port 9222 and port 9223

but when I do

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9223 --user-data-dir="C:\selenum\ChromeProfile"

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9223")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9223') # Recommended is 9222
chrome_driver =  "Data/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

It responds with

```
Opening in existing browser session.
```

Which means it's not opening that session on a different port but on the same one. I want to control the second instance of google chrome, not the first already opened.

How can I avoid this and open multiple google chrome instances on different ports?

Answer (score 3):

Use the latest version of Chrome, I'm using(104.0.5112.102)

create some empty folders like C:\selenum\9222 C:\selenum\9223 (Windows system)

last set shortcuts path like below

run shortcuts,and you will see the result

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9123 --user-data-dir=C:\selenum\9222

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9123 --user-data-dir=C:\selenum\9223

Comment: Indeed, it's mandatory to have a unique user profile (stored in user-data-dir) for each Chrome instance running on a specific debugging port.

Answer (score 1):

1. use Chrome portable (s) or chrome+chrome portable
2. different users on the same windows same computer
3. different computers.
4. Edge and Chrome

Haven't found any way to do this with two instances of chrome.